# Strange Minecraft Noise

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I built a house in survival mode and went behind it into a forest to get some wood. A really deep noise noise followed by a very loud screeching noise played.

It freaked me out so I ran back to my house and exited the game for a bit to collect myself. Now I'm not a baby but I've never heard that noise before and when I searched all the cave noises minecraft uses, the same noise wasn't there.

I logged back in and went back to the same area and there aren't any caves nearby. I also went into spectator mode and there still aren't caves nearby.

Later on I decided to move because my house was too small and I wanted to build in a better area that was closer to my farm and barn so I left the house empty for a little bit.

When I decided to turn it into a form of courthouse, just for the heck of it, and was remodeling it, THE SOUND PLAYED AGAIN.

Please tell me what this is or else im destroying the house and moving as far away from the area as possible! I just don't want some strange new mob coming out of nowhere and killing me!

Answer (score 1):

The sound you heard was very likely one of the intermittent [ambient sounds](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ambience) that play when you're in a dark area (the linked site lets you play each sound so you can check to see if one of the sounds is the same one you heard). It might be a little unsettling but they're harmless noises. If you're hearing them inside your new base it's an indicator that you haven't lit it up enough and you have some areas that are dark enough for mobs to spawn.

It also could be an [Enderman screech](https://gamepedia.cursecdn.com/minecraft_gamepedia/c/ce/EnderStare.mp3), which is the sound that plays whenever something aggros an Enderman.

Comment: I have had Endermen screech my eardrums out but not attack me. But they might just be bugged.

Comment: @SkyPaul I think if an Enderman gets damaged by water/rain they stop attacking you, and they will also screech if something else like a stray arrow from a Skeleton hits them. I think what I was really trying to get at is that the Enderman screech is quite recognisable and most player's would know it if they heard it... I might rephrase that last sentence as I'm not happy with it.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using bedrock edition (phone, consoles other than ps4, ipad and more) there is a new 1.12.0 update which made sounds louder and changed them. If you recently updated, the sound may have changed. If you do not like hostile mobs, then you can change the difficulty to peaceful. If you still hear the sound, then it is probably a bug. Try restarting your device, (not resetting the whole device and erasing data, but completely turning off the device and back on). Hope this helps!